# python sqlite3 in-memory database, memory usage

Tags: sqlite, python-3.6, in-memory-database

I've been experimenting with a in-memory sqlite3 database, via python 3.6. I've measured the speed of its creation and the time that some queries take, but I want to measure how much memory it uses, as it is in-memory.

One method, which is not very precise is multiplying pragma page_count by pragma page_size, but I want something more precise, and I couldn't find any documentation in python that could do this job.

I would really appreciate some help in this matter, thanks in advance.

Comment: The C API has [sqlite3_memory_used()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/memory_highwater.html), but that's all memory used by it, not just for a given database (and I don't know if the python bindings provide it).

Comment: The [dbstat](https://www.sqlite.org/dbstat.html) virtual table is another possibility.